# Conversion from char to byte

Tags: java, char, byte

How a character is converted into byte in java?
If I write

```
char c=12;
byte b=(byte)c;
System.out.println(b);
```

Then the result is 12,as expected 
But...
if,I write

```
char c='\u0012';
byte b=(byte)c;
System.out.println(b);
```

Then the result is 18.
How???

Answer (score 6):

The `\u0012` is actually in hexadecimal format, so its value is `18`. For `12` , you have to use `\u000c` .

Example -

```
char c='\u000c';
byte b=(byte)c;
System.out.println(b);
>> 12
```

Answer (score 5):

Because '\u0012' is hexadecimal for decimal 18.